# Unable to conjure long distance

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I play using a Breton and am at level 100 . With conjuration ability of over 160 . But still I cannot conjure Atronachs seven times away from the player . Its like a bug in the game . I can only conjure atronach just seven steps away . When i was a 5 times away i was able to conjure to long distance . Why is seven times away conjuration doesnt work

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing, that you use the Mod "Skyrim Redone" and would suggest to install the "Unofficial Skyrim Redone Patch" (i.e. from here: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/37605/). This has solved some issues for me.

Comment: Is there any data that would support this, just out of curiosity?

Comment: In the Readme of the unofficial Patch I found the passage
`• Summoner70 correct [...]
Now you can summon dremora five times as far away` I thought, this might solve the similar problem for atronachs as well.